# Who has succeeded in demonstrating the Lense-Thirring effect?

Tags: gravity, rotation

Who has succeeded in demonstrating the [Lense-Thirring effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lense%E2%80%93Thirring_precession)?

This effect is one that describes the rotational motion of the Earth from a space-time structure. This effect is the "drag" of the geometrical structure of space-time due to rotational motion of the object which causes the gravitational-inertial field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lense-Thirring frame dragging has been measured to about 10 or 20% accuracy by two satellite experiments.  Look up [LAGEOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAGEOS) and [GP-B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_Probe_B) (Gravity Probe B).